# How to get Google to do a deep index of my content?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, structured-data

Previously Google was unable to find events on the site I'm working on because it was restricted to logged in users. We specifically added a small feature to view upcoming and past events by popularity. Each page contains X number of structured data 'event' objects (each with schema.org object properties etc.), and my goal has been to get Google to index this data.

My site has ~65k total events, 21k in the future and 44k in the past. Overall, Google only recognizes 5,293 total indexed items (as per Google Webmaster tools, adding up all the www/non-www and http:/ versus https:// and combinations etc.), and on the Structured Data tab of the same tool it shows only 1,413 items (I assume of all the indexed content, these are the only ones it is labeling as events?).

I requested a "fetch as Google and render", with a deep-index to fetch pages linked to the requested page (only 10 of these to use per month), for urls for the base /upcoming-events and /past-events, as well as upcoming & past-events?page=3, but so far I've only seen 1500 pages indexed.

Should I just wait more time?

Could the paging setup (it's not fully implemented yet) be missed by Google?

Here is the [source url](https://www.vuevent.com/past-events?page=3) if anyone wants to examine the content (for relevance only).

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked several times already on Pro Webmasters in various forms. To speed up indexation you need to improve the domain authority and rankings, Google and other search engines prioritise resources to what they believe is 'IMPORTANT', if your site is treated as less important, you get less allocated crawl time, dead simple but can be tricky if your content is considered low-quality.

Comment: I feel like your comment has nothing to do with my answer, but I'm guessing it was auto generated. I disagree with the duplicate posting as I don't think my problem has *anything* to do with the size of my content (nothing to do with page rank or server strength.. those are ludicrous).

Comment: The message was not automated and I understand your disappointed, but there dozens of answers, questions and so forth for sites with huge indexations issues with Google. If you can't find a suitable answer then its because no one has left one in the existing questions, we have many ways of bumping old questions through quality edits and running bounties if you want more, or better answers. Note I never implied rankings & domain authority was the only factor, but are they among the mains. But, you could just Google, and your find a overwhelming amount of evidence to support my ludicrous claims.

Comment: Sorry for sounding rude, I meant that his answer is a far cry of my question's focus. I suppose you're very experienced in this stack exchange and there is a high volume of unique situations like mine that just can't be answered because of complexity issues. So many Google support threads, this was a shot in the dark, thanks anyway!